# Pass Data with Angular Router in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I'm trying to send data between a page and a detailsPage. But I'm receiveng all items and i can't display in ionic. I can see them only in console.

this is my code from main page.ts:

```
openDetails() {
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: {
        contents: this.contents
      }
    };
    this.router.navigate(['drinkdetails'], navigationExtras);
  }
```

this is my code from detailsPage:

```
constructor(private storage: Storage, private dataService: DataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { 


        if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
          this.data = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.contents;
          console.log(this.data)

      };
    }
```

This is html from details page where I want to display.

```
    <ion-content padding>

  <ion-item *ngIf="contents">
    <p>{{contents}}</p>

  </ion-item>


  </ion-content>
```

Please help.

How can I pass only that data assigned to a specific clickable card?

Comment: I not sure how you declare your contents in your page.ts. Make sure it has value under this.contents.description. if your text is actually store in this.contents then your html should be {{data}} only

Comment: In this way I'm passing data between pages with State, but I;m passing all data from that json. How can I filter the data to get only that part that i need to display . How can I add that value?

Comment: Display it like {{data.yourkey}}